# Autolayout with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am using autolayout in Xcode and am creating a fairly tall (1300px) ViewController with a uiscrollview to navigate up and down. I made the viewcontroller freeform so its dimensions are [375,1300]. I then incorporated the scrollview, added the content view as well as all the subviews & constrained everything, leaving no constraint errors. At runtime there are no errors, but everything is all smushed into the normal screen size when I intended for it to be very tall (~1300px) and scrollable. Any clue as to what I am doing wrong?

Below is a diagram showing the issue where:

1. The Outer Black Blox is the ViewController's view
2. The Inner Black Boxes are subviews
3. and The Blue Box is what is displayed on the screen

[image: picture describing my question]

Comment: I think you'll need to describe the constraints you used. It sounds like your constraints might involve the scroll view rather than it's content view, or something like that.

Comment: Remove the constraint that makes the contentView's height the same as the parent view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your correct @Ryan Cocuzzo. I think you need to set sub view priority from 1000 to 250. See below screen shots.

1) Select height constraint of the subview

[image]

2)Then go to show to size inspector

[image]

3) Now change the priority constraint from 1000 to 250.

[image]

4)Finally you get like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following are true:

1. The 4 content views are subviews of the `UIScrollView`, not your view controller.
2. The autolayout constraints on the 4 content views must reference the UIScrollView only, not the view controller's view.
3. The 4th box cannot have a bottom constraint.

It looks like the 4th box has a constraint to make it's bottom align with the bottom of the view controller's view. This would force the other views to smush up together. The 4th box also cannot have a bottom constraint so that the scrollview can resize itself to encompass it's subviews.