# UIScrollView in Xcode using Springs and Struts

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I am managing an application in iOS using swift language and Spring and Struts for positioning. For some reasons I have to use `UIScrollView` in it. But I couldn't found it's correct way of implementing using "Springs and Struts" layout positioning technique.

I am setting the view `height` to "FreeForm" and then `Content View` height to 1000 px but all things are showing in the same screen size.

[image: This is my simulator screen]

[image: This is what I am doing in Xcode story board]

Comment: I con't understood your problem exactly, but you try my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48068995/autolayout-with-uiscrollview/48072122#48072122

Comment: @iOS You have done this using auto layout, I am not using auto layout. I am doing this using Springs and Struts

Comment: Ok, I understood ....

Comment: @iOS have you used scrollview other than auto layout before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Struts and Springs is [no longer recommend](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/228/), you should be using [AutoLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/).

However, if you must:

1) Disable / Uncheck "Use Auto Layout" in `Files Inspector` for the View Controller, this will also disable trait variations.

2) Change your Simulated Size to "Fixed" in the `Size Inspector` for the view controller. Ensure the Simulated Metrics for Size is set to "Inferred" in the `Attributes inspector` for the view controller.

3) Add views and set the autoresizing mask's "struts and springs" to tell the view how to grow and shrink within its superview.

4) set the view's desired frame rectangle to the position relative to it's super view.

[image: Assistant Editor View of Xcode]

You will have to set the scroll view's height manually, since there are no other views to constrain the frame and allow the autoresizing to kick in. To do this, set scrollView's content size after the view controller loads. see `viewDidAppear(_:)` Otherwise the layout engine cannot determine the vertical spacing between the top of the button to the top of its superview (the scrollView).

[image: ScrollView AutoResizing Mask]
[image: Button AutoResizing Mask]
[image: Simulator View]

Again, this isn't advisable and you should consider migrating to AutoLayout.

Comment: Given you and OP mean Autoresizing masks when you say 'Springs and Struts', the application will not get rejected just because you are using autoresizing instead of autolayout.

Comment: No, Assuming the layout is implemented correctly OP shouldn't have an issue with the review process. not for simply using autoresizing. But instead for for layout issues for multiple devices that interfere with [General Layout Considerations](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/#General%20Layout%20Considerations), these guidelines changed after iOS7 to include the design and behavior of that layout (during rotation and user interaction).

Comment: @BangOperator I removed the statement from the post, I don't feel it sends the right message and doesn't add a lot value to it, without prior knowledge of the history of autolayout it can be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

The setting for "FreeForm" is only for interface builder, so you can have a complete view of all the content in your scroll view, but it won't reflect on your app.

The height of the scrollview depends on it's content, so you need to add elements from the top down so it gets bigger.

Comment: So what changes would I have to made for doing this in storyboard using springs and struts